# ValueError("unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 185",)

Tags: mysql, formatting, python-3.4, mysql-python

I am trying to execute a query which lists certain values of my db that match the inputs of my html search form. I want it to do the search even if some of the form inputs are empty inputs.I am using Python 3.4  and my query is something like this:

```
query=("select DISTINCT val1,val2,val3,val4 from tab1,tab2 WHERE tab1.val1=tab2.val1 AND onoma LIKE '%' AND epitheto LIKE '%' AND (val4 between % AND %)" )
data =(d1, d2, d3 ,d4)
c.execute("SET NAMES utf8")   
c.execute(query,data)
```

the error I get is this:

```
ValueError("unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 185",)
```

Please, if you know how i can fix this, i would really appreciate it. I'm a begginer with databases.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Double the `%` characters to escape them.

Comment: Ah, no, you meant those to be placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders for parameters are spelled `%s`, not `%`:

```
query = """
    select DISTINCT val1,val2,val3,val4 from tab1,tab2
    WHERE tab1.val1=tab2.val1 AND onoma LIKE %s AND
          epitheto LIKE %s AND 
          (val4 between %s AND %s)
"""

data = ('%{}%'.format(d1), '%{}%'.format(d2), d3 ,d4)
c.execute(query, data)
```

Note that you should **not** add quotes around placeholders (leave those to the database driver), and for a `LIKE` query, you need to add the wildcards to the parameter value. I used `str.format()` here to put `%` wildcards before and after each value. A LIKE query *without* wildcards (so `%` or `_`) may as well just use `=` equality tests.

Comment: I changes to the exact way as shown above and this is what i got:         ProgrammingError(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"select DISTINCT val1,val2,val3,val4 from tab1,tab2 WHERE \' at line 1') at this line           c.execute(query, data)

Comment: @LoriKougioumtzian: Great, so the parameter part is now working! You now have a SQL query error. Does your query work in MySQLAdmin or another tool?

Comment: I test it out on Mysql workbench and if I make the %s to '%s' it does not have any syntax errors. It does not show any records though, maybe my query is wrong for this situation? Shouldn't be resulting in all the tab1's and tab2's  records since all it has after LIKE is the wildcads?

Comment: Also I tried changing one of the values to a string, and it does not find the records that match to that string either. So I guess there is something wrong with my query..

Comment: @LoriKougioumtzian: remember that each `%s` is a *placeholder*, that the Python MySQL database driver will replace with a properly quoted value. So in MySQL Workbench you'd replace those with actual values from `d1, `d2`, etc.

Comment: So since my data comes from an input in my html file it could be an empty string right?